# SSIS: import MAX(filename) from folder

Tags: sql-server, variables, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I need to pick one `.csv` file from `\\\Share\Folder\` with max filename for further import to SQL. File name is alphanumerical, e.g. `ABC_DE_FGHIJKL_MNO_PQRST_U-1234567.csv`, where numerical part will vary, but I need the only max one each time the package runs.

Constraints: no write access on that SQL server, I use ##Temp table for import and this is the least desirable method for filename processing (no for each loops on this server).

Ideally it will be function/expr-based variable (combined with script task if needed) to pass into connection manager. Any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using a for each loop to load into an ADO recordset then MAX out of that? (the second part I'm not so sure on)

Comment: You can do this with a script task, more details in the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use a Script Task

- Add a variable of type String *User::CsvFile*
- Add a script task to your project and add your created variable as a *ReadWriteVariable*

[image]

- In Your Script task write the following code *(VB.NET)*:

*You have to Import **System.Linq** Library*

```
Public Sub Main()

    Dim strDirectory As String = "C:\New Folder" ' Enter =the directory
    Dim strFile As String = String.Empty

    strFile = IO.Directory.GetFiles(strDirectory, "*.csv", IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).OrderBy(Function(x) x.Length).Last


    Dts.Variables.Item("CsvFile").Value = strFile

    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success

End Sub
```

- Then use this variable from Flat File Source

Comment: Nice! I see Linq is everywhere and everytime I am suprised and impressed.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid this library is really amazing and powerful

Comment: I can see the power even if I hate it cause it's not SQL :)

Comment: Hi Hadi, Thanks very much. Sorry for late reply - was busy with other priority tasks. However, I have "OrderBy is not a member of System.Array" error. I suppose LINQ is already in place as it is .NET Framework 4.0. If not, how can I import it?

Comment: Ahh. found this - Imports System.Linq. Please disregard above.